# wrong argument type nil (expected String) (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, file, null, arguments, typeerror

I have a problem.

My problem is that I am trying a few functions of RubyVM and getting an error message with the method "load_from_binary".
I have already looked on the internet, but found no answer.

My question is: what do I have to do to change the code so that it goes and what did I do wrong? How can I avoid this mistake in the future?

The code looks like this:

```
vm1 = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("puts 'Hello World'")

File.write("test.iseq", vm1.to_binary)
str = File.read("test.iseq")
vm2 = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary(str)
```

The principle: The data should be saved from vm1 in a file (binary format) and loaded in vm2 from the file.

I would appreciate an answer.
Best regards
Marek K.

Comment: what ruby version you got ?

Comment: can you post your configuration file too

Comment: My ruby version is: `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]`.I'm programming on a Windows 10 computer. What is a configuration file and where can I find it?

Comment: and file config ?

Comment: What do you mean file config?

Comment: If you call `vm1.to_a`, you can see that there are extra entries in the array that [are not documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-i-to_a). So, it seems there have been changes to the instruction format that aren't documented. It is very possible that they also haven't been implemented in the instruction sequence loader. As far as I know, everything under the `RubyVM` namespace is considered an internal API that is not guaranteed to work.